# Fetch database table rows as asp.net gridview headers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have two tables in my SQL Server database (one for adding subjects and other for adding marks obtained in those subjects based on class). I want to make marks entry just like excel entry so I'm fetching student names in the first column of the gridview and populating textboxes in other columns of the gridview to enter the marks as shown here:

[image]

Now the problem is that if student 'A' of class 10 has selected 4 subjects and student 'B' of class 5 has selected 5 subjects, how do I implement the marks entry module being said that student 'A' gets only 4 textboxes and subject columns in the gridview and student 'B' gets only 5 textboxes.

This is my Aspx markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdMarksEntry" GridLines="None" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
     CssClass="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl. No.">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name of the student" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSub1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSub2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject 3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSub3" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject 4">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSub4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject 5">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSub5" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject 6"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSub6" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my c# code behind:

```
private void bindgrd()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnect"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection StudMarksCon = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand StudMarksCmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct name from studentregistration where class='" + drpClass.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and div='" + drpDiv.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                StudMarksCmd.Connection = StudMarksCon;
                sda.SelectCommand = StudMarksCmd;

                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    grdMarksEntry.DataSource = dt;
                    grdMarksEntry.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You either create a column for all possible subjects and leave the value null for students not in the subject or you change your design. A common patterns is master/detail where you might select a student from one grid and that specific student's data is loaded into another section below or on another page.

Comment: Yes I can do that but if I add new subjects and allocate it to a new class then this won't work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the number of text boxes dynamically based on number of subjects that the student selected.